# Get keys and values from Multimap

Tags: java, multimap

I want to print all the keys and all the attributes of an object from a multiMap.
The same key can have different objects.

I have created the multiMap with the following code:

```
Multimap<Integer,Country> country=ArrayListMultimap.create();
```

My Class country is:

```
class Country {
    String country;
    int population;
}
```

How can i retrieve all the object attributes from it:
With HashMap i was using the following code:

```
 for (Map.Entry p : country.entrySet()) {
    Country country=(Country)p.getValue();
    nameCountry=country.country;
    population=country.population;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use keySet() to avoid repetitions, keys() if you want repetitions. Then get the country instance via get(..)

Comment: never used Multimap before , I have seen some examples with string and integer but not with a class object. Do you have any example?

Comment: As as value or key? It is pretty much the same as maps (invoking the hashCode() for the key object) but not deleting the existing key if a repeat comes about

Answer (score 1):

Use almost the same but instead of `entrySet()` use [`entries()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html#entries--):

```
 for (Map.Entry<Integer, Country> p : country.entries()) {
     Country country=(Country)p.getValue();
     nameCountry=country.country;
     population=country.population;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use keySet to get unique keys and then get the collection for the key.

```
 for (Integer key : countries.keySet()) {
      Collection<Country> collection = countries.get(key);
      for (Country country : collection)
      {
        String name = country.country;
        int poplulation = country.population;
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Give my example of using it

```
Multimap<String, String> NameList = ArrayListMultimap.create();

    NameList.put("david", "1");
    NameList.put("david", "2");
    NameList.put("jonathan", "4");
    NameList.put("david", "2");

    Collection<String> values = NameList.get("david");
    System.out.println("all david list: " + values);

    Iterator iterator = values.iterator();
    System.out.println("first element: " + iterator.next());
    System.out.println("second element: " + iterator.next());
    System.out.println("third element: " + iterator.next());
 System.out.println("number of david elements "+NameList.get("david").size());
```

the printed result will be

```
all david list: [1, 2, 2]
first element: 1
second element: 2
third element: 2
number of david elements 3
```